# Does Andrew Ng's ANN from Coursera use SGD or batch learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

What type of learning is Andrew Ng using in his neural network excercise on Coursera? Is it stochastic gradient descent or batch learning?

I'm a little confused right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about session-based course (which I have passed previously): https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

than it uses a batch-learning approach, in exercise 4 (which covers ANN). If you carefully study the cost function you will see that it is calculated using all of available examples, not just one randomly chosen.

Comment: Thank you, Maxim! I was in fact speaking about that specific course you've linked. Somehow I got a bit confused about that issue, so, again, thank you for clearing this up. :)